# Configuring Real VNC on RHEL 6.3 Command Line

Tags: command-line, vnc

I am trying to setup real vnc server on my RHEL via command line.

I have done the following steps

1. Downloaded the Real VNC installer from [Real VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc) for Red Hat 64 bit system
2. Unizipped it to get to rpms VNC-Server-5.0.5-Linux-x64.rpm,VNC-Viewer-5.0.5-Linux-x64.rpm
3. The documentation did not have any command line installation instructions
4. Followed the instructions given in this [forum](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/linux-tutorials-howtos-reference-material/971-installing-running-vnc-redhat-rpm-linux.html)
5. `rpm VNC-Server-5.0.5-Linux-x64.rpm -i`
6. `vnclicense -add <KEY>`
7. `netstat -an | more`

   ```
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5901                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5902                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5903                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
   ```
8. On windows 7 I installed RealVNC Viewer and tried connecting to the server, I get
   an error promt `connect: Connection refused (10061)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start vnc session from your Linux account to be able to connect to your session, run `vncserver` from your command line of your Linux system. After you issue this command it will tell you your session ID to connect. Here is an example:

```
         [root@systemname]# vncserver

         New 'systemname:1 (username)' desktop is systemname:1

         Starting applications specified in /username/.vnc/xstartup
         Log file is /username/.vnc/servername:1.log
```

If the above task is already covered then you may need to make sure that firewall on your Linux side as well as windows side is disabled for specified port `5901` or `5902`.., related to the connection ID that you are trying to connect. if you are using SELinux then you need to make sure that is also configured to allow your VNC session.